# Wo kommt "meinen" in der Bedeutung von "lieben" vor?

Tags: meaning, history, meaning-in-context

Im Lied "Die Freiheit, die ich meine", das hauptsächlich in Burschenschaften gesungen wird, und das auch als Titel des Buches von Jörg Haider gedient hat, kommt das Wort "meinen" im Sinne von "lieben" vor (verwandt zu Minne).

Gibt es noch andere verbliebene Phrasen oder zusammengesetzte Wörter, wo diese Bedeutung erhalten ist?

(Wie zum Beispiel Meinungsfreiheit :-) )

Comment: aha, das ist mir neu. Ich wusste, dass das *mein* in *Meineid* im Althd./Mhdt. *falsch* hieß.

Comment: Ist mir auch neu.  "Die Freiheit, die ich meine" verstand ich immer als "Diese eine Definition von Freiheit, die ich mei, äh, um die es mir hier geht".

Comment: Duden (online) hat diese Definition nicht.  @thei hast du nen Link?

Comment: @splattne, @jae: Im Grimm unter "meinen, verb.", Abschnitt 5e. Kann nicht linken, weil der Linkgenerator vom DWB irgendwie kaputt ist. *häufiger aber hat sich geradezu die bedeutung lieben herausgebildet, wo dann wol auch meinen mit minnen, später mit lieben verbunden erscheint*. Man könnte hiervon natürlich einiges für eine Antwort zitieren, aber die Frage von @thei zielt wohl eher auf Wendungen ab, die heute noch üblich sind. "Freiheit, die ich meine" wird in diesem Abschnitt jedenfalls auch zitiert, mit "M. v. Schenkendorf in Wackernagels leseb. 2, 1529" als Quelle.

Comment: Das [Liederlexikon](http://www.liederlexikon.de/lieder/freiheit_die_ich_meine) zitiert ein paar Beispiele für die Rezeption dieses Liedes, bzw seines Titels, im späten 20. und frühen 21. Jahrhundert (siehe dort unter V.).

Comment: Es existiert auch noch die Bedeutung von "die Meinen" -> "die Geliebten" oder "Angehörigen"

Answer (score 5):

[Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Minne) gibt ein weiteres Beispiel:

ursprünglich: das Gedenken (zu: meinen, im Mittelalter in der Bedeutung lieben, vergleiche "es mit jemandem gut meinen").

Comment: Welcome to the site. An upvote to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Ich denke, dass heute kaum jemand den Titel in seiner ursprünglichen Bedeutung wahrnimmt, sondern in der heute üblichen Bedeutung des Wortes "[meinen](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=meinen)".

Mir sind auch keine anderen solchen Beispiele bekannt.